# Can you apply CSS rules, in CSS, if a div doesn't exist?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is this possible, with CSS ?

Apply this rule if .div1 doesn't exist:

```
.div2{
  property: value;  
}
```

like

```
<div class="div1">
...
</div>

<div class="div2">
 <!-- it exists, so do nothing -->
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="div2">
 <!-- it doesn't exist, apply the css -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is impossible with CSS. To acheive this effect, use Javascript.

Answer (score 22):

Exists, or doesn't exist? Your question confuses me :)

---

**Apply style to `.div2` if `.div1` exists:**

**Option 1:** `.div2` follows *directly* after `.div1`

```
.div1 + .div2 {
  property: value;
}
```

**Option 2:** `.div2` follows `.div1` as a sibling:

```
.div1 ~ .div2 {
  property: value;
}
```

---

**Style `.div2` without `.div1`:**

It's a bit of a hack, but you could do the reverse.
Style .div2 normally, and then override the styling with the selectors above.

If `.div1` doesn't exist, `.div2` gets the normal styling.

```
.div2 {
  background: #fff;
}

.div1 + .div2 {
  background: #f00; /* override */
}

/* or */

.div1 ~ .div2 {
  background: #f00; /* override */
}
```

Comment: Do you know how we could make this work if .div1 was below .div2 and we wanted to style .div2 based on whether .div1 was available?

Comment: No. There is no selector to go 'backwards' in the DOM tree :/ Depending on the layout, you could possibly have them in the correct order in the DOM, but style them absolute/relative to look like they are switched. However, I'd probably use a css class instead.

Comment: css class to traverse backwards in the DOM tree?

Comment: A css class on .div2, if you have a backend language to determine if div1 is rendered or not.  If not, you could use javascript to check if div1 or there or not, and add a class to div2.

Answer (score 17):

If you know the 'unstyled' styles of the div, you could use a css sibling selector to style it one way if it follows .div1, and the 'plain' way if it doesnt - ie

```
.div2 {
    /* styled however you want */
}
.div1 + .div2 {
    /* 'plain' styling */
}
```

[See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6ztrV/) Try removing div1 to see div2 as it would be styled without div1

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, no, you can't do that.

But you may 'hack' it using CSS selectors, I'm referring to to:

- `+ .something` selector
- `~ .something` selector

I'd use the second selector, which is the "general sibling" selector.

Given the HTML you posted you can apply the style to the `.div2` class and then reset it using the `.div1 ~ .div2` selector.

So something like this:

```
.div1 {
  color: red;
}

.div2 {
  color: blue;
}

.div1 ~ .div2 {
  color: black;
}
```

In this way, with the first HTML snippet the `div2` will be black and with the second snippet it will be blue.

Answer (score 2):

### NO

With CSS alone, the `if` conditions which check the availability of an element, is not possible. You should use JavaScript, (jQuery is recommended).

Notes: With CSS you can check some conditions of an element, like checking if an element has an attribute (like `input[type=text]`), or checking if an element is the first element of a list (like `p:first-child`), etc. But you can't check anything from the element's sibling elements, or ancestors. Also you can't check the negative conditions most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. But you can create class "div3" and in your code determine whether DIV1 exists and in that case apply the "div3" class instead of "div2"