# Change margin top of div based on if div exists

Tags: css

Is it possible to add `margin-top` based on if an `id` exists or it isn't hidden?

For example, if `#radio3` exists, I set `margin-top: 260px`, if it doesn't, I set `margin-top: 230px`.

```
    #radio3 + #radio4 {
        margin-top: 260px;
    }
    #radio4 {
        margin-top: 230px;
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS alone?

Comment: Can [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121847/can-you-apply-css-rules-in-css-if-a-div-doesnt-exist/8122047) help you?

Comment: css alone, no. little bit of help from javascript, yes

Comment: Can you give us the scenario where you want to do this? It sounds more like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you tell us your overall goal, we might be able to help you come up with  a better alternative